# How to mock static with PowerMock without using PowerMockRunner?

Tags: powermock

`@Runner` doesn't play well with `@ClassRule` so I'm trying to use:

```
@ClassRule
public static PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();
```

But then `@PrepareForTest` does nothing.

My code looks something like:

```
@PrepareForTest({SomeClass.class})
public class DynamicVipTest {
    @ClassRule
    public static SomeClassRule someClassRule = new SomeClassRule();

    @ClassRule
    public static PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setupClass() {
        PowerMock.mockStatic(SomeClass.class);

        expect(SomeClass.someMethod().andReturn("someValue").anyTimes();
    }
}
```

The `expect` winds up calling `SomeClass.someMethod` rather than creating an expectation.

What's the latest and greatest way to mock statics?

Comment: Are you using PowerMock in conjunction with Mockito or EasyMock?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, there's a better 'solution' than the following:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({SomeClass.class})
public class DynamicVipTest {
    public static SomeClassRule someClassRule = new SomeClassRule();

    @ClassRule
    public static PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() {
        someClassRule.before();

        PowerMock.mockStatic(SomeClass.class);

        expect(SomeClass.someMethod().andReturn("someValue").anyTimes();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownClass() {
        someClassRule.after();
    }
```

}

Comment: OP asked for an example without using @PowerMockRunner.class